# Need to replace 0 with 1 in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

let value2 = Grp.Count(x => x.Column1 <= 2 && x.Column2== "studentName") * 100 / **Grp.Count(x => x.Column2== "studentName")**

in this the Bold is zero sometimes and it give me infinity i want to replace it with 1 if value is zero.

Comment: How you would do it without linq?

Comment: Rolled back an edit because it erased the boldface.

Comment: Is this LINQ-to-objects (where you can add any method of your own), or LINQ-to-SQL/LINQ-to-entities where it needs to be translated into SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a C# Extension you can do something like this. Add this class into your namespace.

```
 public static class DataFormatter
 {
    public static int CheckForZero(this int value)
    {                                
       return value == 0? 1 : value;
    }
 }
```

And then you can do this.

```
 let value2 = Grp.Count(x => x.Column1 <= 2 && x.Column2== "studentName") * 100 / 
   Grp.Count(x => x.Column2== "studentName").CheckForZero(); //add this check
```

---

Else you can use the usual ternary operator like below..

```
 var initialCount = Grp.Count(x => x.Column2== "studentName");
 var refinedCount = initialCount == 0?  1: initialCount;
```

Comment: Better use variable to store that count and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an external variable or if you don't mind the performance hit, just use an Any() with a ternary operator. Linq's Any will return true if the predicate matches atleast one value, so if you find a match, it will find the count. Otherwise it will just return 1 in the denominator.

```
let value2 = Grp.Count(x => x.Column1 <= 2 && x.Column2== "studentName") * 100 / (Grp.Any(x => x.Column2 == "studentName") ? Grp.Count(x => x.Column2== "studentName") : 1)
```

Using an external variable would look like:

```
let valueStudentName = Grp.Count(x => x.Column2== "studentName") 
let value2 = Grp.Count(x => x.Column1 <= 2 && x.Column2== "studentName") * 100 / valueStudentName != 0 ? valueStudentName : 1
```